# Курсор в конец contenteditable div JS

Tags: javascript, html, html5, contenteditable

У меня есть `contenteditable div`, мне хочется чтобы ссылки автоматически оборачивались в тег `<a>`.

Я сделал это с помощью `regex'ов`, но после обновления содержимого div'a с помощью метода `innetHTML` курсор сбивается в начало текста.

Как мне это исправить?

Comment: Делайте это все по другому.

Answer (score 0):

При взаимодействии с контентом элемента напрямую, c помощью метода [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) Вы полностью переписываете его содержание.

Как результат этой операции позиция каретки `contenteditable` элемента возвращается к исходной. Для того что бы это поправить Вам потребуешься управлять ее местоположением самостоятельно.

Это достаточно просто сделать с помощью методов [createRange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createRange) и [getSelection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection):

```
const moveCaretToEnd = targer => {
    const range = document.createRange()
    const selection = window.getSelection()
    range.selectNodeContents(target)
    range.collapse(false)
    selection.removeAllRanges()
    selection.addRange(range)
    target.focus()
    range.detach() 
}

moveCaretToEnd(yourContenteditableElement)
```